# Sending Unicode Characters greater than 0x7F through RS232

Tags: vb.net, unicode, serial-port

My application is in Windows CE 6.0 using Compact Framework and is being used to issue remote commands to a device through RS-232. These commands are send using bytes with specific hex values, e.g. sending 0x22 0x28 0x00 0x01 as a command sequence. I'm sending the bytes one at a time. The hex values are stored internally in a string for each command sequence, e.g. "22,28,00,01".  I'm sending the bytes using the following code.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim SendString() As String
Dim SendByte, a As String

DutCommand = "22,0A,00,02,E7,83"     'Sample command string
SendString = Split(DutCommand, ",")  'Split the string
For i = 0 To UBound(SendString)      'Send each byte after encoding
     SendByte = Chr(CInt("&H" & SendString(i)))
     CommPort.Write(SendByte)
Next
```

SendByte is being properly encoded even for values greater than 0x7F but the last two bytes being sent (0xE7 and 0x83) are being sent as 0x3F, the ASCII code for "?" since it's greater than 0x7F.

Am I missing a setting for the Comm port to handle encoding? Is there a simple method for sending the data with values greater than 0x7F?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to convert the hex values to bytes.  It needs to look like this:

```
    For i = 0 To UBound(SendString)      'Send each byte after encoding
        Dim b = Byte.Parse(SendString(i), Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
        CommPort.BaseStream.WriteByte(b)
    Next
```

The non-stringy way is:

```
    Dim DutCommand As Byte() = {&H22, &H0A, &H00, &H02, &HE7, &H83}
    CommPort.Write(DutCommand, 0, DutCommand.Length)
```

Comment: Thanks. The byte conversion is exactly what I needed. A quick test was highly successful, now to run it through a couple dozen command sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using [SerialPort.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8(v=vs.110).aspx).

If so, notice what the documentation says:

> By default, SerialPort uses ASCIIEncoding to encode the characters. ASCIIEncoding encodes all characters greater than 127 as (char)63 or '?'. To support additional characters in that range, set Encoding to UTF8Encoding, UTF32Encoding, or UnicodeEncoding.

Seems like the solution is pretty clear.  You'll need to set the `CommPort.Encoding` property to the desired value.

See [SerialPort.Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8(v=vs.110).aspx) for `SerialPort.Write`:

> By default, SerialPort uses ASCIIEncoding to encode the characters.
>   ASCIIEncoding encodes all characters greater than 127 as (char)63 or
>   '?'. To support additional characters in that range, set [Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) to
>   UTF8Encoding, UTF32Encoding, or UnicodeEncoding.

You could also consider [using the `Write` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx) that actually just writes the raw bytes.